# How to get entire thread using twitter API?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I have used the following code to get replay using twitter Search, I wanted to find data of entire thread.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import requests
from requests.auth import AuthBase

# Fill these in. Generate tokens at https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps.
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''

query = urllib.parse.quote("from:TwitterDev")

url = f"https://api.twitter.com/labs/2/tweets/search?query={query}&expansions=in_reply_to_user_id&max_results=20"

headers = {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
}

# Generates a bearer token with consumer key and secret via https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token.
class BearerTokenAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret):
        self.bearer_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"
        self.consumer_key = consumer_key
        self.consumer_secret = consumer_secret
        self.bearer_token = self.get_bearer_token()

    def get_bearer_token(self):
        response = requests.post(
            self.bearer_token_url,
            auth=(self.consumer_key, self.consumer_secret),
            data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'},
            headers={'User-Agent': 'LabsRecentSearchQuickStartPython'})

        if response.status_code is not 200:
            raise Exception("Cannot get a Bearer token (HTTP %d): %s" % (response.status_code, response.text))

        body = response.json()
        return body['access_token']

    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers['Authorization'] = f"Bearer %s" % self.bearer_token
        r.headers['User-Agent'] = 'LabsResearchSearchQuickStartPython'
        return r

# Script starts here.

#Create Bearer Token for authenticating with recent search.
bearer_token = BearerTokenAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

#Make a GET request to the Labs recent search endpoint.
response = requests.get(url, auth=bearer_token, headers=headers)

if response.status_code is not 200:
    raise Exception(f"Request reurned an error: %s" % (response.status_code, response.text))

#Display the returned Tweet JSON.
parsed = json.loads(response.text)
pretty_print = json.dumps(parsed, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
print(pretty_print)
```

I was only able to get replay by the TwitterDev, not by other users

I want to get all the replay in a thread, What should i do?

Comment: The new Twitter API v2 will have an operator for retrieving Tweets associated to a thread, but the launch has been delayed for a short period of time. Hold tight!